# How to pass ssh password asked on terminal while using subclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, subclipse

Our internal `svn` repository's URI looks like `svn+ssh://svn/hogehoge/svnroot/`. Using `subclipse` on eclipse that is run from a terminal, eclipse freezes when I try to access repository and never return. I found on terminal `ssh` password is asked but looks like it's just printed there and doesn't accept my input (password I enter is interpreted as command on terminal). Any idea is appreciated.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Eclipse Indigo SP2
- Subclipse (Required) 1.6.18
- Subversion Client Adapter (Required) 1.6.12
- Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (Required) 1.6.17

Comment: Do you need to use a password, or could you set up an SSH key for password-less access?

Comment: @blahdiblah Your idea could be a direct solution to my particular question, but using SVNKit gave me easier access to svn server before trying yours. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you install SVNKit and change to using it instead of JavaHL.  SVNKit includes a pure Java SSH client so it is able to provide a GUI prompt within Eclipse.  There are two alternatives if you want to use JavaHL:

1. Start Eclipse from a Terminal window.  SSH prompts will then appear within that window.
2. Run ssh-agent.  Your SSH client will then fetch the keys from ssh-agent and will not need the terminal prompt.

Usually users are already using ssh-agent, in which case I would recommend just using JavaHL.  Since you are apparently not using it, I would suggest to just use SVNKit.

Comment: Nicely done. Perfect solution since I didn't need to stick to JavaHL, I just use SVNKit. Thx!